# getFullYear() is not a function

Tags: angular7

I am developing web app by using `Angular`. When I upgrade my app to `Angular7`, Date function is not working. It gave me error such as

> DateTime.getFullYear is not a function

It was ok before I upgraded to `Angular7`. In package.json:

```
"typescript": "^3.1.1", "@angular/cli": "~7.0.2",
"@angular/complier-cli": "~7.0.0".
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Remember next time you post a question to paste the code relating to your error so that someone can have a look at it, since the same error can result from different code.

After upgrading my ng6 app to ng7 my `DateTime.getFullYear` worked fine, until I changed something about it, and it suddenly gave the same error. Everything seemed fine.

Checking my date object like below returned an object just the way it should

```
dateFunction(longdate) {
    console.log(typeof(longDate))  // This returned 'object' which is correct
    longDate.getFullYear() // Would get the same error here
}
```

So I tried passing in a fresh date object into the function, and not one being send via parameter like this:

```
dateFunction() {
    longDate = new Date();
    console.log(typeof(longDate));  // This returned 'object' which is correct
    longDate.getFullYear(); // This worked fine now
}
```

And this would work fine, so I realized it is not my `getFullYear()` function that is wrong, but my parameter that is corrupt.

But here is the strange part, so I went to the parent component and did the same thing there - I deleted the old code and made a fresh `longDate = new Date()` and send it through to my function, and suddenly it was working. The exact same code, but I just re-wrote it.

Try creating a fresh date just before your function, pass it in and see if it works. If it works then it is not your function but the old `date` variable that is corrupt.

PS: I just feel that I have to say that you must use the `new` keyword (see examples above) when creating your initial date variable, or it will also throw the error...